# I have an Uncaught Reference Error that says a function is not defined, even though it seems to be defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform some javascript code when an input field's input changes. I started by specifying an oninput event handler function name.

```
<input type="text" name="venue_name" value="<?php echo $event->venue_name(); ?>"
    class="form-control w2bw2c-name w2bw2c-venue-name" placeholder="Search..." 
    oninput="inputChange()">
```

I had the inputChange function defined outside my document-ready function, and this worked for a while, but now it is not working. Now I have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="venue_name" value="<?php echo $event->venue_name(); ?>"
    class="form-control w2bw2c-name w2bw2c-venue-name" placeholder="Search...">
```

Within my document.ready function I have:

```
$('select.w2bw2c-name').input(function() {
    inputChange(this);
});
```

Outside my document.ready function, I have the function:

```
function inputChange(x) { 
    ... some code ...
};
```

Now when I enter some text into the input field I get the message that `inputChange` is not defined. Perhaps it is complicating that I must use a class as a selector, but the input field may appear multiple times within a form, and I got it to work initially.

Comment: What is the exact error message? You should be getting a complaint that `input` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

`.input()` isn't the valid way to attach the `input` event, you should use `.on()` instead, like :

```
$('select.w2bw2c-name').on('input', function() {
    inputChange(this);
});
```

**NOTE :** Your selector refer to a `select` tag when you've an input, it may be :

```
$('input.w2bw2c-name')..
```

Instead of :

```
$('select.w2bw2c-name')..
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the selector should have been input.w2bw2c-name, but the event is still not firing either with .on or .input.

Comment: I'm not getting the "inputChange not defined" message, but the event is not firing. Could this be a timing problem?

Comment: I'd still like to know why my first example, using oninput="inputChange()" didn't work and gave the error message that the inputChange function was not defined. This technique seems to fire the event I'm looking for, whereas using a selector with .input or .on doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I had my javascript at the end of my HTML. I moved some of it (the so-called "undefined" functions) to the head of my HTML and the events fired as they were supposed to. Problem now is that the called function inputChange makes an AJAX call to the database and not all the data is getting returned (to populate an autosuggest list). I'll save that for another question.